# compare two dates of unknown format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like two compare two dates with moment. I know I can go for

`moment(firstDate).isSameOrBefore(secondDate)`

but the problem is, that the format of the dates is unknown. There are two possible formats:

- iso string '2019-07-01'
- converted locale date '23.07.2019' (german format)

I do know the language locale and I know the conversion which is done via

```
formattedDate: function() {
  if (!this.date) {
    return ''
  }

  moment.locale(this.locale);
  return moment(this.date).format('L');
}
```

So when it comes to the comparison both dates could be raw iso strings or formatted dates.

How can I compare two dates of unknown format?

---

I tried to convert both dates to the same format but I am not sure if this is the right way (and no errors might come up)

```
const firstConvertedDate = moment(firstDate).format()
const secondConvertedDate = moment(secondDate).format()
return moment(firstConvertedDate).isSameOrBefore(secondConvertedDate)
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, you say -> `I do know the language locale`, and then you say `two dates of unknown format`.   If you know the format the second parameter is the format,..eg.  `moment("23.07.2019", "DD.MM.YYYY")` will parse your German date format.

Comment: The problem is that I am looking for a solution that works for every language out there. When I know I format the iso date with `L` I can convert the date back to iso?

Comment: But you know the locale?.. eg.  `moment("23.07.2019", "L", 'de')`   And if you wanted then to show in English format,  `moment("23.07.2019", "L", 'de').locale("en").format("L")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't guess the format based on the provided string. For example the string `"10/7/2019"` would be ambiguous, since it allows both `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy`. If you know the locale you can simply provide it to the `.moment()` function.

```
moment(dateString, "L", locale);
```

```js
var dateString = "10/7/2019",
    display = "YYYY-MM-DD",
    en_us = moment(dateString, "L", "en-us"),
    en_gb = moment(dateString, "L", "en-gb");

console.log(
  en_gb.format(display),
  "<",
  en_us.format(display),
  "//=>",
  en_gb.isBefore(en_us)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: is there a way to check if the date is a iso date or formatted locale date? As I mentioned before I don't know which one it is so I don't know if I have to format it

Comment: @hrp8sfH4xQ4 You should direct users to input it in a certain format. Alternatively you can use the [`<input type="date" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) element, which uses the build-in datepicker on **almost all** modern browsers. This sets the value in ISO format, but presents it to the user in the locale saved in the browser settings. See the bottom of the linked page for browser compatibility. You could also use a third-party datapicker like jQuery datapicker.

Comment: it's a pity that js does not have php's `strtotime` analog